# Determining the Place according to latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using google maps API to determine a building(Place) which is a Google Point of interest. I'm trying to get the place reference for future use. but due to API limitation or whatever limitation. I can't get the exact place. As an example below latitude longitude belongs to "The university of Sydney". Using this code I could derive University of Sydney but as second result and also I tried many lat long but sometime appropriate result comes in the end or first. These places are prominent to Google Places Search system. The radius of this request looks lame to me. Is there any way to retrieve the exact place ?

```
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88858402464521, 151.18735671043396);    
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 1,
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}
```

Advanced Thanks

Comment: 2 points you might want to note: 1) The radius is in meters. 2) You can specify [types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) for your request. University of Sydney is listed in the following types: university, school and establishment.

Comment: There is also a [rankby](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) parameter that can be set to DISTANCE and that might help sorting the results.

Comment: @mrupsidedown: I have just showed an example. I need all the building types In the sense All Google points of interests but the result should only consist the exact place. I have even tried distance, which gives me more results.

Comment: Try a [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) then.

Comment: It doesn't give me the exact place name but the address.

Comment: You *need all the building types* but the result *should be the exact place*. But that *exact place* is also a road and a locality. How could Google know that you are searching for the University and not the adjacent road or the locality itself?

Comment: Exact place is not a road. Just places. Google POI. Lat and long is in the building's bound. Nearby search works fine but it gives me more than one (nearby places) which not in the radius which I have specified