# Google Places API - Incomplete list of types

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to get a full list of the supported types by the google places api. Supposedly, a list like this is offered in https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types . However, some of  the possible types are missing (e.g. university).

Do you know where could I find (if possible) a complete list?

P.S. Possible duplicate -- > [Google Place - Supported Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809296/google-place-supported-types). 
However, no one replied and I couldn't comment cause of my low reputation. Hope I am not violating the rules of the community :).

Comment: There is no University type provided by google 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

Comment: Also this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205428/determining-the-place-according-to-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: To be honest I don't still need that, but it's strange because when you get the data from the google API you could find the 'university' type and much more than those mentioned in the "supported_types". But it seems that the taxonomy of the types doesn't exist anywhere.